# How to use Validations in sails.js?

Tags: validation, sails.js

I want to use 'ip' validation but I tried something like

```
attributes: {
  type: 'string',
  ip: true
}
```

but it always refuse when I gives 192.168.2.1 or any other ip.

I know there is a list of available in this page http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models

However, they don't explain how to use each one. If anyone knows other good document or any rules on usage, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to give your attribute a name.  Then to use the IP validator, set the `type` of the attribute to `ip`:

```
attributes: {
  ipAddr: {
    type: 'ip'
  }
}
```